# Why do i get "no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: python, proxy, request, activesupport, proxies

I have checked other posts but they do not seem to resolve this.

this is my code.

```
  def main():
    while True==True:

        random_proxy = random.choice(read)

        proxies = {
            proxy_type: random_proxy
        }

        response = requests.get('https://manacube.com/play/', cookies=cookies, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Page View Sent (Code 200)")
        else:
            print("Error")

for x in range (int(t)):
    Thread(target=main).start()
```

THE ERROR IM GETTING IS :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 49, in main
    response = requests.get('https://url.com/play/', cookies=cookies, proxies=random_proxy, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mazin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 700, in merge_environment_settings
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I am not sure if this is a dumb error but i am new at python so please do not make fun of me, please help if you can, i want to choose a random proxy out of proxies.txt and use it every request.

so

request 1:
111.68.31.155:8080
request 2:
203.210.84.198:8080
request 3:
150.136.120.227:3128

Comment: I think you meant to use `proxies=proxies`, not `proxies=random_proxy`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried this, it removed the error. but now it doesnt get random proxies it only gets one and sticks with it for all the requests

Comment: There's probably some problem with the `while True == True` loop.  Please fix the code indentation in the post, so we can see what is actually part of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this and it worked with me**

It's using:

```py
pro = {
       'http://': random_proxy,
       'https://': random_proxy
     }
```

Instead of:

```py
proxies = {
            proxy_type: random_proxy
        }
```